# A poorly posed time dependent perturbation benzene type ring question

Tags: perturbation-theory, molecules, quantum-chemistry

In my first year masters QM class my professor recently mentioned an example that he said he would either give on an assignment or possibly put on our exam. We have all our assignments now and it hasn't been asked so I am motived to try to understand this!

I am paraphrasing but he said to consider a ring, such as a benzene ring, with an electron that has a unit of angular momentum, and now replace one of the carbon atoms with say, silicon. He said that breaking the symmetry makes this a time dependent perturbation question.

I can see how changing one of the atoms could be treated as a perturbation, but I don't see how the time dependence comes in? I'm just learning this topic so I'm not really sure where to begin, applying the formulas and ideas I've learned to a model like this is more challenging.

Even if it doesn't wind up being an exam question it seems like a good practice one, and the way he mentioned it makes it sound like it is a standard pedagogical question, but so far I can't find anything like it, though I may not be posing the question properly. If anyone can guide me that would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

from my understanding of your system, the basic hamiltonian for a ring of size N is $$t\sum_{n=1}^N\left(|n\rangle\langle n+1|+|n+1\rangle\langle n|\right)+\mu\sum_{n=1}^N|n\rangle\langle n|$$.
If you now fix the angular momentum, this would fix the eigenfunction.

The perturbation mentioned happening at time t could be to add a term $$\delta H=\Theta(t)\delta\mu|k\rangle\langle k|$$

Modifying the onsite potential at site k from time 0 onward, leading to a time dependant perturbation.